# WINDOWS 10: Installing Win10 with MediaCreationToolx64 and keeping files

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-7-x64, windows-10

So I was one of the unlucky who didn't get the reservation on my PC despite meeting all the requriments.

Now I would like to update to win 10 using the  MediaCreationTool by Microsoft.

My concert tho is, would updating the system this way be the same as with the reservation?

Meaning will I get to keep my files, and have the option to go back within 30 days?

I'm running win7 Home Premium x64 SP1

Will be glad for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it and I kept all my files and apps.

I also have Windows Rollback (The option to go back that u mentioned)

I was running win8.1 x64

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it then now

Comment: In any case better to create a backup to prevent losing all if something in the installation crashes

Answer (score 0):

The best option for me. Open the computer, remove the system Hard drive, and get an empty one installed in the PC or laptop, and then install the new Op System you want to try, do the drivers, updates, put some of your software, and test it for a while. If you don't like it, just change the H Disk for the old one.